# PHP code vulnerable to SQL injection: how to work with `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

As I was learning from couple of years old tutorials I have end up with following code which IS vulnerable for SQL injections.

Can someone explain to me how to work with `mysql_real_escape_string()`?
Is this currently bulletproof method?

```
//Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
    $str = @trim($str);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $str = stripslashes($str);
    }
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

//Sanitize the POST values
$usr = $_SESSION['usr'];
$live = (isset($_POST['live']))?1:0;
$created = date("F j, Y, g:i a",time()+60*60);
$title= clean($_POST['title']);
$content = clean($_POST['content']);

//Create INSERT query
$qry = "INSERT INTO news( usr, live, created, title, content) VALUES( '$usr', '$live', '$created', '$title', '$content') ";
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: +1 for good code. It is OK provided that `$_SESSION['usr']` was already sanitized!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. **In this case.**

Note there is nothing like "universal sanitization". Let's call it just *quoting*, because that's what its all about.

When quoting, you **always quote text for *some particular output***, like:

1. string value for mysql query
2. `like` expression for mysql query
3. html code
4. json
5. mysql regular expression
6. php regular expression

For each case, you need different quoting, because each usage is present within different syntax context. This also implies that the **quoting shouldn't be made at the input into PHP, but at the particular output**! Which is the reason why features like `magic_quotes_gpc` are broken (I recommend to keep it switched off).

So, what methods would one use for quoting in these particular cases? (Feel free to correct me, there might be more modern methods, but these are working for me)

1. `mysql_real_escape_string($str)`
2. `mysql_real_escape_string(addcslashes($str, "%_"))`
3. `htmlspecialchars($str)`
4. `json_encode()` - only for utf8! I use my function for iso-8859-2
5. `mysql_real_escape_string(addcslashes($str, '^.[]$()|*+?{}'))` - you cannot use preg_quote in this case because backslash would be escaped two times!
6. `preg_quote()`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this one is fine. [You can use prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), though

Do not use @ to hide all errors!

Comment: +1 for prepared statements. Not only they prevent SQL injections, but also can make certain queries much faster!

Answer (score 2):

Everything you append to query string you should escape with `mysql_real_escape_string`. It will prevent most of SQL injections. But better use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

**Example:**

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,$username,$pass);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("select * from Table where id=?");
if ($stmt->execute(array(1))){
    $content = $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

See [PDO::__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) for reference

Comment: @JOHN - can you give an example of usage?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is bulletproof when it comes to hacking; having said that, yes.. mysql_real_escape_string() prevents SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your method is sql injection save.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like

```
sprintf(" SELECT * from table_name WHERE value = '%s'", mysql_escape_string("$var_value"));
```

---

> The %s from the sprintf() function indicates that the argument is treated as and presented as a string.
>
> If an attack is made such as the one from the previous example the query sent will be:
>   view source
>   print?
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE username='john' AND password='\' OR \'\'=\''
> ```
>
> and will return an empty result set. [(source)](http://www.bitrepository.com/sanitize-data-to-prevent-sql-injection-attacks.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can use mysql_real_escape_string, to escape dangerous characters...

```
$sanitized_query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table WHERE field='%s', mysql_real_escape_string($value));
```